# I'm building a RPG style tile engine in Pygame and am stuck on animations

Tags: python, pygame, game-engine

As the title said, I'm trying my and at building an RPG engine in python using the pygame library. Having already been able to build a simple mapping engine, I decided to try creating the player object.  Currently I have two classes, gameObjects and a main class. I've been able to build a player object that moves throughout a "gridded surface." I've done this using this code:

```
    def move(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        self.timeElapsed = time.time()-self.start
        while (self.timeElapsed < .1):
            self.timeElapsed = time.time()-self.start
        self.x += self.movex
        self.y += self.movey
```

this allows the player to move with whatever speed I choose, and is called during the game loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    (code to make the controls, basically modifies the players movex or movey)
player.move()
```

This all works fine, but the next step I need is to have the player instead "slide" between the spaces, that is they don't simply jump to the next space but instead have a smooth movement between the spaces. I've tried a few things that were quit silly, but can't seem to figure out the proper way to go about this.
Thanks!

Edit: fairly important thing I forgot to mention is that when displaying the player, I multiply their x and y by 32, which is what creates the 32x32 grid. Here's the code:

```
screen.blit(player.img, (player.x*32, player.y*32))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `self.x` is an integer with the same resolution as your grid (`self.x+1` points to the next whole grid position), you need to add a fractional part for the moving in-between. But you don't have to add that in the actual player coordinates, it's only necessary when drawing.

Something like:

```
screen.blit(player.img, (player.x*32 + offset, player.y*32 + offset))
```

where you initialize `offset` with 0, and make it increment to 32 in a number of steps. The number of steps is up to you; `1` makes the image move slow, `16` almost immediately jumps to the next position. (Depending on the delay, of course, between two consecutive draw operations.) Note that you need some additional logic to move either left or right and up or down.

You may want to think about this, at the current stage of development: you can choose *when* to do this intermediate stepping; either one character at a time ("on demand"), or, turn-based style, when you press some "done" button. In the latter case, you'd loop over all of your moving characters and move each of them with the same offset, so they seem all to move at the same time.